# z-index woes: Can't get navgational drop down to appear above slider

Tags: css, z-index

Got a weird one because in some cases, it works and in others, it doesn't. I'm currently wrapping up a site and on this page (http://panchosrestaurant.com/drinks/beer/) there's an issue when you rollover the 'Drinks' button. A drop down appears, as it should, but the graphic frame which is the last element of my RevSlider is appearing above it. Went to Inspector and it says the z-index for that element is 5. Fine. So I tried to make the ul, li, li a, all sorts of different elements a 6 or much, much greater and yet the frame continues to appear on top of it. Where am I going wrong? Am I targeting the incorrect element?

Comment: It would help if we could see the code you are using. Please add it to your question using the "edit" link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element with class `tp-static-layers` has a `z-index` of 505...

You have to put a z-index of at least 506 on the dropdown element `<ul class="sub-menu">` to win. Or refactor some of your styles.

Comment: This works. Setting `.main-navigation li` directly to a z-index of 506 or greater also works.

Comment: Yes because the `<ul>` element is composed with `li` ones, but it's better to put the style on the `sub-menu` element, i.e. on the `ul`. Semantically, you need the style on the element as a whole, not on each part of it.

Comment: Where did you find that setting? I couldn't locate that anywhere for 505? Thanks, BTW.

Comment: It is in the RevSlider plugin stylesheet called `settings.css`, line 116

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS block below you should set the z-index to something higher than 505, which is what your image border is set to.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px)
.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul, .main-navigation ul li:focus > ul, .main-navigation .focus > ul {
  clip: inherit;
  overflow: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code i would assume all you need to do is to apply a position to the element you want to be over z-index: 5

Answer (score 0):

Just add `z-index: 999;` to your `.main-navigation li` class:

```
.main-navigation li {
   margin: 0 14.1px;
   margin: 0 0.88rem;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 999;
}
```

**[Edit]**

As **@Michael P** pointed out, the `z-index` only needs to be at `506` to trump the `.tp-static-layer' class